# Let $I$ be a left ideal of the ring $R$. Prove that $L=\{ r\in R | rx=0, \forall x\in I \}$ is an ideal of $R$.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $a,b\in L$. Then $a\in L\Rightarrow ax=0$ and $b\in L \Rightarrow bx=0$. Therefore, 

$ax-bx=0\Rightarrow (a-b)x=0\Rightarrow (a-b)\in R.$

Let $c\in L$ and $d\in R$. How do we show that $cd,dc \in L$ ?

Comment: This is straightforward. Let $x \in I$. Can you see that $cdx = dcx = 0$?

Comment: I see clearly how $dcx=0$, but since the ring is not commutative, I don't see how $cdx=0$.

Comment: The ring need not be commutative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$c\in L\Rightarrow cx=0\forall x\in I\Rightarrow dcx=0\forall x\in I\Rightarrow dc\in L$

$d\in R\Rightarrow dx\in I\forall x\in I$(As $I$ is leftideal)

So $cdx=0\forall x\in I$(As $c\in L$ and $dx\in I$) Thus $cd\in L$